# Writing integer to binary file

Tags: python, file, integer, serialization, io

I wrote a python function that writes a integer to a file in binary form. But are there any ways that I can reduce the number of steps, is there a more efficient way to write a integer to a file?

```
def IntWrite(FileName, Integer):
    #convert to hexadecimal
    data = str('{0:0x}'.format(Integer))
    #pad number if odd length
    if(len(data) % 2 != 0):
        data="0"+data
    #split into chucks of two
    info = [data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]
    #convert each chuck to a byte
    data2 = "".join([chr(int(a, 16)) for a in info])
    #write to file
    file(FileName, "wb").write(data2)


#convert back to integer
def IntRead(FileName):
    RawData = file(FileName, "rb").read()
    HexData = "".join(['{0:0x}'.format(ord(b)) for b in RawData])
    return int(HexData, 16)


IntWrite("int_data.txt", 100000)
print IntRead("int_data.txt")
```

Comment: This is more of a SO question. See [struct](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/struct.html#module-struct).pack, struct.unpack, in this case with a format character of `i` or `I`, unless you need more than 32 bits.

Comment: … but it's also acceptable as a Code Review question.

Comment: Sure, especially if there is a need to handle arbitrarily large integers, which the original code seems to offer. Otherwise the best code is that which you don't have to write. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python comes with a built-in [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module for serialization:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('data', 'wb') as f: pickle.dump(9 ** 33, f)
>>> with open('data', 'rb') as f: print(pickle.load(f))
30903154382632612361920641803529
```

(P.S. I wouldn't use a filename ending with `.txt` to store binary data.)

Comment: Note that pickle's binary format is incompatible with the original question.

Comment: Yes, that's right: I'm assuming here that the OP is starting from scratch.